# jQuery's .done() and .always() never getting called

Tags: javascript, api, jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to do a simple ajax api call, but my jQuery `.done()` and `.always()` callbacks are never getting run, even after a successful call.

Here's where I do the api call:

```
join: (e) ->

    e.preventDefault()
    email = $('.email').val()

    $.ajax(
      type: 'POST'
      url: '/api/email'
      data: { email: email }
    ).done((msg) ->
      console.log 'POST success'
      console.log msg
    ).always((msg) ->
      console.log 'Always'
    )
```

Here's the `post` from my controller:

```
app.post '/api/email', (req, res) ->

    console.log req.body
```

The problems that my server is correctly receiving the data from the api call, but my jQuery callbacks never get fired.

```
{ email: 'test@email.com' } // What gets logged server-side
```

**EDIT**

So I tried adding a `.fail()` method and switched up the code a bit to see if my syntax was wrong, but this new code is still functioning like the old code.

```
request = $.ajax(
  type: 'POST'
  url: '/api/email/beta'
  data: { email: email }
)

request.done( (msg) ->
  console.log 'POST success'
  console.log msg
)

request.fail( (msg) ->
  console.log 'POST Fail'
  console.log msg
)

request.always( () ->
  console.log 'Always'
)
```

**EDIT 2**

I just realized that the `POST` is actually "failing", but after 4.1 mins... But the weird thing is that I'm still getting the data in the req.body object...?

Here's a screenshot of network from chrome tools:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to catch the "fail"?

Comment: what is the response status also any error in the console

Comment: @tilix, take a look at the edit

Comment: @ArunPJohny, there is no error in either chrome tool or my console. What gets logged is this: `{ email: '' }`, which is what is expected because that's what I send over the wire

Comment: @ConnorBlack: Where does your server respond with something? What does the network inspector tell you?

Comment: Could you please get the deferred object: `deferred=$.ajax...` and then console.log it in the console after 2 or 3 seconds and post the object to see what happened ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you receive the request at the server (and log it), but then don't do anything about it. This eventually leads to a timeout. Change it to

```
app.post '/api/email', (req, res) ->
    console.log req.body
    res.write(JSON.stringify({success:true})/* or whatever*/);
    res.end();
```

Maybe you're using some framework with special methods on the `res` object; if so then look up its documentation about how to answer a request.

Comment: This did it. I'm using express, didn't know that I had to explicitly end the request. Thanks though!

Comment: Ah, then just [`res.send`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send) should do it; afaik no `end` required there.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST'
      url: '/api/email'
      data: { email: email}
    }).done((msg) ->
      console.log 'POST success'
      console.log msg
    ).always((msg) ->
      console.log 'Always'
    )
```

Comment: Braces are optional in coffeescript, but I did try it that way and the code is still behaving the same.